# Using AVX to xor two zmm (512 bit) registers

Tags: c++, gcc, inline-assembly, avx512

I would like to bit-wisr xor zmm0 with zmm1.
I read around the internet and tried:

```
asm volatile(
            "vmovdqa64 (%0),%%zmm0;\n"
            "vmovdqa64 (%1),%%zmm1;\n"
            "vpxorq %%zmm1, %%zmm0;\n"
            "vmovdqa64 %%zmm0,(%0);\n"

            :: "r"(p_dst), "r" (p_src)
             : );
```

But the compiler gives "Error: number of operands mismatch for `vpxorq'".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Inline asm for this is pointless (**https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm**), and your code is unsafe and inefficient even if you fixed the syntax error by adding the 3rd operand.  Use the intrinsic `_mm512_xor_epi64( __m512i a, __m512i b);`  as documented in intel's asm manual entry for `pxor`: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pxor.  Look at the compiler-generated asm if you want to see how it's done.

Comment: Unsafe because you don't have a `"memory"` clobber to tell the compiler that you read/write memory, and you don't declare clobbers on zmm0 or zmm1.  And inefficient for many reasons, including forcing the addressing modes and not using a memory source operand.  And not letting the compiler pick which registers to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most AVX512 instructions use 3+ operands, i.e. you need to add additional operand - dst register (it can be the same as one of the other operands).

This is also true for AVX2 version, see https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pxor:

> VPXOR ymm1, ymm2, ymm3/m256
>
> VPXORD zmm1 {k1}{z}, zmm2, zmm3/m512/m32bcst

Note, that the above is intel syntax and would roughly translate into *mm1 = *mm2 ^ **mm3, in your case I guess you wanted to use `"vpxorq %%zmm1, %%zmm0, %%zmm0;\n"`

Be advised, that using inline assembly is generally a bad practice reserved for really special occasions. SIMD programming is better (faster, easier) done by using intrinsics supported by all major compilers. You can browse them here: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/

Comment: The OP is using AT&T syntax, where the destination is the last operand, not the first.  So just quoting that part of Intel's manual isn't the most helpful thing.

Comment: @PeterCordes I disagree, since I didn't refer to or stated the operand order anywhere in my answer. Just that additional operand needed. I hope the person, who tries to program in assembly, can figure out for themselves whether it needs to be the first one or the last one. I'll clarify nonetheless.

Comment: It's still helpful, but I meant it's not as helpful as it could have been.  You did quote the Intel-syntax `VPXORD zmm1 {k1}{z}, zmm2, zmm3/m512/m32bcst` which obviously has the destination first and the source last.

Comment: You also didn't point out that the inline asm is still broken, only now the bug is not a syntax error, it's safety: missing clobbers like I commented on the question.  I guess I should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Inline asm for this is pointless (**https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm**), and your code is unsafe and inefficient even if you fixed the syntax error by adding the 3rd operand.

**Use the intrinsic `_mm512_xor_epi64( __m512i a, __m512i b);`** as documented in [Intel's asm manual entry for pxor](https://felixcloutier.com/x86/pxor). Look at the compiler-generated asm if you want to see how it's done.

**Unsafe because you don't have a `"memory"` clobber to tell the compiler that you read/write memory, and you don't declare clobbers on `zmm0` or `zmm1`.**

And **inefficient** for many reasons, including forcing the addressing modes and not using a memory source operand. And not letting the compiler pick which registers to use.

---

Just fixing the asm syntax so it compiles will go from having an obvious compile-time bug to a subtle and dangerous runtime bug that might only be visible with optimization enabled.

See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for more about inline asm.  But again, there is basically zero reason to use it for most SIMD because you can get the compiler to make asm that's just as efficient as what you can do by hand, and *more* efficient than this.